# Argocd - Brand new cluster and brand new error - ooohooo

Tags: devops, continuous-deployment, argocd, argo, gitops

Something is off with my ArgoCD Setups:

> ComparisonError: Failed to load target state: failed to generate
> manifest for source 1 of 1: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc =
> connection error: desc = "error reading server preface: remote error:
> tls: certificate required"

I created appset and nothing showed up. SO I created an application manually from  the UI and this is the error I see.

Any clue what I am missing here folks? I did added the tls certs (root, intermediate certs) same as other working cluster and this one is throwing new error.